# Positioning UISwitch in UITableView for iPhone, iPad, and Retina

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a grouped TableView and I've positioned a UISwitch to the right side of the row, just to the left of the ">". For now, I've used an explicit CGRect (no calculated values).

In iPhone 4.2 it is positioned correctly, but of course on iPad 4.2 it's not.

Are there specific ways to calculate positioning that will yield the same relative placement regardless of the device/screen res?
Or do I just use the screen width, table cell width, etc., and calculate it myself?

Comment: u can use for each of your components the formula : ipadVersion.width = iphoneVersion.width * 768 / 480. This is a simple example for the case of finding out the width only in the Portrait mode. Of course using the same model u can find out the x, y and height. The fact is that the result is a stretched version of the iPhone version. I don;t think there is another option

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with `UIView` [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) and `UIView` [`autoresizesSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizesSubviews). Saves you a lot of agony.

Answer (score 0):

For customized views (like a `UITableViewCell` subclass) you can use `layoutSubviews` to do your custom view positioning:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // layout relative to contentView frame
    switchView.frame = CGRectMake(
        CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(switchView.frame) - someMargin,
        4.0f / y, // or something else related to the contentView
        CGRectGetWidth(switchView.frame),
        CGRectGetHeight(switchView.frame)
    );
}
```

You can use also autoresizing masks to automate repositioning of subviews. This will work for your case (positioning to the right of a container view), but is less useful if you want to position relative to a sibling view.